# Sorting list of list by custom function

Tags: python

I' ve a list of lists and i' d like to sort them primarily by the first (zeroth) element, secondly by a custom function with python 3.5, but i' m unable to do it.

```
lst = [[1, 'A', 2], [2, 'C', 3], [2, 'A', 4], [2, 'B', 5], [3, 'D', 6]]

def cs(lst):
    if lst[1] == 'A':
        return 1
    if lst[1] == 'B':
        return 2
    return 3

lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], cs)
```

. This is what i tried but i can' t find out why i don' t get the expected result, which is: 1A, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3D .

Anyone has an idea?

The problem is that for some reason the cs method does not run (if i put there some printing message, it' s not printed).

Comment: `lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], cs(x)))` ?

Comment: shouldn't it be `lst.sort(key=lambda x: cs(x[0]))`?

Comment: The `lambda` you provide to `sort` is the function that will be called by `sort`. It will *not* call any function that you return from that function. You need to call it yourself: `(x[0], cs(x))`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort by second value and in case of tie take first value into account:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

Comment: `lst.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1,0))` is the more preferred method if I'm not mistaken